# Allow another app to write set of files using FileProvider

Tags: android

I need to share a directory of appA's internal storage with appB so that appB can write a set of files to it. The number and names of files are not known a priori to appA.

To do that I came up with this strategy:

1. Set up a FileProvider in appA
2. At share time, appA uses grantUriPermission with FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION to share the *a directory* with appB, not a file.
3. Then appB fires an intent to appB with an Uri pointing to the shared directory.
4. appB receives the intent, gets the uri within it and uses Uri.withAppendedPath to generate an URI for a child file.
5. appB uses ContextResolves to write to the childUri
6. appB repeats #5 and #6 for each file it wants to write.

This does not work because the permission does not extend to child uris. What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. If you use
FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION in grantUriPermission, the permission will apply to any child url of the grant one.